# HTTP Error 500 for my PHP script?

Tags: php, html, syntax

so I'm having a itty bitty problem here. When I try to send data (or just visit it via a webpage), it returns an HTTP 500 Error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, and I've looked everywhere to find my answer. Appreciate any help, thanks!

```
<?php
function createNewEntry($file, $country, $ip, $isp, $host, $date, $heure, $provenance, $data)
{
    $tmp        = file($file);
    $newPage    = '';
    while($ligneActuelle = array_shift($tmp))
    {
        //if(preg_match("#<!-- Breakpoint -->#",$ligneActuelle)) //si on rencontre le breakpoint
        if($ligneActuelle == "<!-- Breakpoint -->\n") //si on rencontre le breakpoint
        {
            $newPage .= "<tr><td>$country</td><td>$ip</td><td>$isp</td><td>$host</td><td>$date</td><td>$heure</td><td>$provenance</td><td>$data</td></tr>";
            $newPage .= "\n<!-- Breakpoint -->\n";
        }
        else
            $newPage .= $ligneActuelle;
    }

    $monfichier = fopen($file, 'w');
    fseek($monfichier, 0);
    fputs($monfichier, $newPage);

    fclose($monfichier);
}
$country = geoip_country_code3_by_name($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$isp = geoip_isp_by_name($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$ip         = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$host       = gethostbyaddr($ip);
$date       = date("m/d/Y");
$heure      = date("H:i:s");
$provenance = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : 'Unspecified';
if(isset($_GET['g']))   $data   = $_GET['g'];
else                    $data   = 'NOTHING';

createNewEntry("index.php", $country, $ip, $isp, $host, $date, $heure, $provenance, $data);
echo "403, access forbidden!";
?>
```

Anyways, any help is greatly appreciated. I've been scratching my head for a good hour now. Thanks!

Comment: anything in error_log?

Comment: [Mon Nov 28 04:01:57 2016] [error] [client REDACTED] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function geoip_country_code3_by_name() in /var/www/html/c.php on line 34

Comment: and yes i installed the geoip dependency (pretty sure i did at least, i did `yum install GeoIP-devel` and it worked fine

Comment: might also need to 'yum install php-pecl-geoip', and add 'extension=geoip.so' to your php.ini :)

Comment: Just because you installed `GeoIP-devel`, doesn't mean you installed the PHP module `geoip`! Either you install the PHP module or use the webserver to do that (if it has GeoIP (not sure about Apache or Lighttpd, but Nginx has to be compiled with geoip)).

Comment: Jason, are you using Apache or Nginx? As what @CharlotteDunois said, Nginx needs to be re-compiled with GeoIP.